# Avoid Navbar text being cut off

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

The following:

```
  <div data-role="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#page_1" data-transition="none">Heading 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page_2" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Heading 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page_3" data-transition="none">Heading 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page_4" data-transition="none">Heading 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page_map" data-transition="none">Map</a></li>
  </ul>
```

renders as:

```
Hea... Hea... Hea... Hea... Map
```

on my iPhone.

Is it possible to fix it so that it renders something like this instead:

```
Header 1  Header 2  Header 3  
     Header 4    Map
```

Comment: you can do something like this, it's a bit complicated, but it could solve your problem. In the fiddle, resize window then hit RUN to see results. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16264244/1771795

Answer (score 1):

You can style your `<ul>` and `<li>` like this...

```
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align: center;
}

li {
    display: inline;
}
```

This <kbd>[Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/DANq5/)</kbd> displays what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: If this isn't what you're looking for, can you be more specific as to your requirements?